# When can method of undetermined coefficient be used

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm studying about method of undetermined coefficient.

But i can't make sure when method of undetermined coefficient can be used.

I know that the differential equation need to be non-homogeneous and the non-homogeneous terms need to speical form such as polynomials,  trigonometric functions, or exponential functions.

---

what I'm wandering is following:

To use the method of undetermined coefficient, the coefficient need to be constant? and the differential equation need to be linear??

Comment: The surest way to figure out when an ODE solution method can be used is to check if the solution that was found solves the ODE.

Comment: Sometimes you can use the method of undetermined coefficients (or, more generally, parameters) to find particular solutions to nonlinear ODEs. For instance, you can use the ansatz $y=\alpha e^{\beta x}$ to find a solution to $y''=3y^2e^x$, or $f(x)=\alpha x^{\beta}$ to find a solution to $f'(x)=f^{-1}(x)$. However, there is no guarantee that such solutions satisfy the initial value or boundary conditions.

Comment: The method itself is a guess, an [Ansatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz). No requirements for when to use. It could not yield a solution, or only yield some solutions when more exist.